# why doesn't decodable struct is not conforming of a custom struct variable

Tags: swift, variables, struct, decodable

hey guys I am newbie to swift plz go easy on me :) ,
trying to take custom variable to conform to decodable .

```
struct pa {
    static var pageIdString:String?
}
struct dataModel1:Decodable{
    let query:Page
}
struct Page:Decodable{
    let pages:pagesidextract
}
//error:-  Type 'pagesidextract' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
struct pagesidextract:Decodable {
   
    let pa.pageIdString : extracting
//error :- Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
//error :-Expected declaration
// error :- Type annotation missing in pattern
    
}


struct extracting:Codable{
    
    let extract:String
    
}
```

Comment: This isn’t an issue with Decodable. You can’t declare a property the way you do, what is `let pa.pageIdString : extracting` supposed to mean? You need to at least remove the dot, `let paPageIdString : extracting`

Comment: Unrelated but please name structs with starting uppercase letter according to the naming convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mismatch with a name of the properties and types.
I mean that line `let pa.pageIdString : extracting`. You declare name of the property with `.` which is disallowed.

If you declare a constant then you should have convention `let name: Type`. And if you want to assign the value it looks like that `let name: Type = value`.

I would recommend to read [The Swift Basics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html).